# Handling the output of jsonb_populate_record

Tags: postgresql

I'm a real beginner when it comes to SQL and I'm currently trying to build a database using postgres. I have a lot of data I want to put into my database in JSON files, but I have trouble converting it into tables. The JSON is nested and contains many variables, but the behavior of jsonb_populate_record allows me to ignore the structure I don't want to deal with right now. So far I have:

```
CREATE TABLE raw (records JSONB);
COPY raw from 'home/myuser/mydocuments/mydata/data.txt'
create type jsonb_type as (time text, id numeric);
create table test as (
select jsonb_populate_record(null::jsonb_type, raw.records) from raw;
```

When running the select statement only (without the create table) the data looks great in the GUI I use (DBeaver). However it does not seem to be an actual table as I cannot run select statements like

```
select time from test;
```

or similar. The column in my table 'test' also is called 'jsonb_populate_record(jsonb_type)' in the GUI, so something seems to be going wrong there. I do not know how to fix it, I've read about people using lateral joins when using json_populate_record, but due to my limited SQL knowledge I can't understand or replicate what they are doing.

Comment: `create table ... as ...` is just a short-hand that tries to define the columns of a table based on the names and types from a `select` query. You might be better off defining the table manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonb_populate_record()` returns a single column (which is a record).

If you want to get multiple columns, you need to expand the record:

```
create table test 
as 
select (jsonb_populate_record(null::jsonb_type, raw.records)).* 
from raw;
```

---

A "record" is a a data type (that's why you need `create type` to create one) but one that can contain multiple fields. So if you have a column in a table (or a result) that column in turn contains the fields of that record type. The `*`  then [expands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION) the fields in that record.

Comment: Thanks, this has indeed fixed it! I'll read about the .* operator to get a better understand of the issues. Also I was not aware that something with a single column is refered to as a record in SQL.

Comment: @Mangobae: I have added a bit more explanation and a link to the manual.